# 100Uncaught ReferenceError: startCase is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor, lodash, multi-select, meteor-blaze

I have been trying to use lodash.js in Meteor js and will need help in doing this. I have tried all methods of appending external file to meteor but still the same error.

I have this [dropdown with search on codepen](https://codepen.io/rustybailey/pen/GJjvYB) I want to use in a template. I have been on this for more than 8 hours today and yet to figure out what to do. Also, I added this package to Meteor when appending urls of external js files did not work and the error persists. This is my implementation:

```
<template name="multiselect">
<div class="instructions">(Click to expand and select states to filter)</div>
    <div class="dropdown-container" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="dropdown-button noselect">
            <div class="dropdown-label">States</div>
            <div class="dropdown-quantity">(<span class="quantity">Any</span>)</div>
            <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-list" style="display: none;">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search states" class="dropdown-search"/>
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is the error i keep getting:

```
VM31646:100Uncaught ReferenceError: startCase is not defined(anonymous function) @ VM31646:100_.each._.forEach @ underscore.js?hash=cde485f…:149(anonymous function) @ VM31646:99DOMRange._insertNodeWithHooks @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:407Blaze._DOMRange._insertNodeWithHooks @ client.coffee:17DOMRange._insert @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:376DOMRange.attach @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:453Blaze._DOMRange.attach @ client.coffee:57DOMRange._insert @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:371DOMRange.attach @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:453Blaze._DOMRange.attach @ client.coffee:57Blaze.render @ blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:2373_render @ kadira_blaze-layout.js?hash=dbd1396…:204(anonymous function) @ kadira_blaze-layout.js?hash=dbd1396…:77_.extend.withValue @ meteor.js?hash=27829e9…:1077(anonymous function) @ meteor.js?hash=27829e9…:464(anonymous function) @ meteor.js?hash=27829e9…:1105onGlobalMessage @ meteor.js?hash=27829e9…:401
```

This works fine without using it in Meteor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have the `underscore` library in your Meteor project, which has the same "`_`" shorthand as lodash does and overrides it. A way to go around that is to use the [meteor-lodash](https://atmospherejs.com/erasaur/meteor-lodash) package, which allows you to call `lodash` functions like this:

```
lodash.each(usStates, function(s) {
    s.capName = lodash.startCase(s.name.toLowerCase());
    $('ul').append(stateTemplate(s));
});
```

Comment: I'm very happy to the extend that if it's been possible on SO to give more than a score I would have. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for a solution this same problem, I had the same problem after following an example in another post.  After digging, it finally hit me that I needed to use the "_." before the function call.
My before code (causing error) was:

```
"Client: " startCase(camelCase(ckifdefined(idata.name))) + "<br>"
```

The fixed code:

```
"Client: " + _.startCase(_.camelCase(ckifdefined(idata.name))) + "<br>"
```